# SharePoint 2010 - Edit user info

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Why can I not (as admin or user) edit a user profile? When I click Edit Item I can only attach a file and I only see the account name. I've gone into the admin area but nothing I change takes affect. I've set some other fields as editable but they don't show. I tried to edit user policies but everything is greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you populating your user profiles from AD? In that case, there is nothing in SP to edit since the data comes from elsewhere.

If not, then where are you trying to edit an item? Are you using Manage User Profiles in the User Profile Service Application area?

Comment: nope. Added it as a local windows account. I want to be able to change what their display name is.